PADDLE : I have not permitted to perform this request
Getting this error: you are not permitted to perform this request paddle, when I'm creating new transaction
Try everything, got a one thing,
https://developer.paddle.com/errors/shared/forbidden#solutions but still no response getting
enter image description here
Thanks in advance, if you get the solution !!!!!

Pay attention to whether your API_KEY belongs to the SANDBOX or PROD environment.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
